# Using firewall to block outbound push notifications apple and android (allow inbound)

Tags: android, ios, notifications, push-notification

I am reading the apple and android push notification docs and notice that there is a bit of a problem for what I want to achieve. I want to block devices from sending outbound notifications or using this service from chat programs etc. while allowing inbound notifications to occur.

Looks like the fashion in which this works is the device goes out to create a lightweight connection that stays alive and the device then requests notifications through this connection.

From my perspective operating a firewall, I have not been able to create a policy to disallow one without the other. I can identify what is a push notification service and block it all or allow it all but this doesn't work for me as all applications use this and inbound outbound as well.

Any ideas here in stack community that you may have that can help?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  I'm having trouble understanding you.  Can you clarify your desired behaviour?  What is "*this service*"?  And can you include any code or config you've tried so far?

Comment: Framework of how the messaging notification protocol or application works within iOS is what I need to learn more about. I see lots of write ups saying it works like this: the client requests and a session begins with the cloud, then the client polls the cloud for new messages, if one is there then it brings the message to the client. The client maintains the session. All this happening really originating from a client to cloud (outbound) session. My firewall sees this and applies policy, but within this session I cannot identify incoming and outgoing messages.